# NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_sellerprofile.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

i'm' trying to create a profile form (2 types of user) but when i create the user using `SellerProfileSerializer` it gives me NOT NULL constraint failed: accounts_sellerprofile.user_id, I  don't wanna to put null=True,blank= True in `user=models.OneToOne` field because this is key information, here is my code. Thanks in advance

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100,default=None,unique=True)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=10,default=None)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email   

class SellerProfile(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User,null=False,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=None)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100,unique=True)
    company_phone = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    company_zip = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    company_phone =  models.CharField(max_length= 50)
    seller_type = models.CharField(max_length = 50 ,choices =SELLER_CHOICES,default ='1')
    seller_product = models.CharField(max_length = 50 ,choices =SELLERPRODUCT_CHOICES,default ='1')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','email', 'password')
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User( email=validated_data['email'],)
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
class SellerProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserCreateSerializer()

    ****def create(self, validated_data):
        user_data=validated_data.pop('user')
        caretaker = SellerProfile.objects.create(**validated_data)
        User.objects.create(caretaker=caretaker,**user_data)
        return caretaker****

    class Meta:
        model = SellerProfile
        fields=('user','company_name','company_phone','company_zip','seller_type','seller_product')

    @receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    def create_auth_token(sender, instance=None, created=False, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Token.objects.create(user=instance)
```

View.py

```
class SellerUsers(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = SellerProfileCreateSerializer
    queryset = SellerProfile.objects.all()
```

Comment: do you want all users have seller profile?

Comment: I have another serializer named BuyerProfileCreateSerializer, When the user is created in the SellerProfileCreateSerializer it will store some information on the SellerProfile and User, and when created in BuyerProfileCreateSerializer it will store information on User and BuyerProfile model

Answer (score 0):

```
# insert your values seperately, so that you can see what are values that you inserting in the database table.

class SellerProfileCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserCreateSerializer()

    def create(self, validated_data):
        caretaker = SellerProfile.objects.create(
            user_id = validated_data['user_id'],
            company_name = validated_data["company_name"],
            company_phone = validated_data["company_phone"],
            ....
            ....
        )
        return super(SellerProfileCreateSerializer, self).create(validated_data)
```

Comment: It now raises a Key Error on id field

Comment: I have edited my answer. You need to pass user_id in your request params like {"user_id":"12"}.

Comment: Still don't work , i've edited my create( ), according to django recomendation on writable nested serializers but still raises NOT NULL constraint failed: on the id field. But still cannot understand whats happening